# Remove "select all" blue droplets on svg click

Tags: android, firefox

Firefox on Android has two blue drops to indicate the selected text, then it gives some more options like `Copy All`  I am getting this behavior when I click an SVG and I am trying to turn it off.

To test yourself, using Firefox on Android click a star:  https://jsfiddle.net/wbzex7c8/

```
.starContainerHeight {
  height: 50px;
}

#centerStarDiv {
  border: solid 1px #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 25px;
}

#centerStarDiv>div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration-color: white;
}

.marginTop0px {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
}

.rating {
  float: left;
  border: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>span {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
}

.rating>span>.star1 {
  color: transparent;
}

.rating>span>.star2 {
  color: white;
}

.rating input:checked~span>.star1 {
  color: #FFED85;
}

.rating input:checked~span>.star2 {
  color: #FFED85;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>span:hover>.star1 {
  color: yellow;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>span:hover>.star2 {
  color: #FFED85;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>span:hover~span {
  color: #FFED85;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>span:hover~span>.star1 {
  color: #FFED85;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>span:hover~span>.star2 {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="rating starContainer">
<input id="star1" name="rating" type="radio" value="1">
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="margin-top:17px" id="span1" starnumber="5"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-star fa-w-18 star1 fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="star" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" starnumber="5">

<path fill="currentColor" starnumber="5" d="M259.3 17.8L194 150.2 47.9 171.5c-26.2 3.8-36.7 36.1-17.7 54.6l105.7 103-25 145.5c-4.5 26.3 23.2 46 46.4 33.7L288 439.6l130.7 68.7c23.2 12.2 50.9-7.4 46.4-33.7l-25-145.5 105.7-103c19-18.5 8.5-50.8-17.7-54.6L382 150.2 316.7 17.8c-11.7-23.6-45.6-23.9-57.4 0z"></path></svg><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-star fa-w-18 star2 fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="far" data-icon="star" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" starnumber="5"><path fill="currentColor" starnumber="5" d="M528.1 171.5L382 150.2 316.7 17.8c-11.7-23.6-45.6-23.9-57.4 0L194 150.2 47.9 171.5c-26.2 3.8-36.7 36.1-17.7 54.6l105.7 103-25 145.5c-4.5 26.3 23.2 46 46.4 33.7L288 439.6l130.7 68.7c23.2 12.2 50.9-7.4 46.4-33.7l-25-145.5 105.7-103c19-18.5 8.5-50.8-17.7-54.6zM388.6 312.3l23.7 138.4L288 385.4l-124.3 65.3 23.7-138.4-100.6-98 139-20.2 62.2-126 62.2 126 139 20.2-100.6 98z"></path></svg></span>
</path>
</svg>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a css property for the svg like so:

```
svg { -moz-user-select: none; }
```

This will fix your issue. It worked for me.